# Tooltip with ListLinePlot and interpolation

Tags: plotting, tooltip

Is it possible to get the coordinates of any point on a graph using Tooltip, ListLinePlot and interpolation ?

For example on this simple example

```
ListLinePlot[{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}//Transpose,InterpolationOrder->2]
```

Thank you

Comment: Your question is vague: do you need the coordinates of *any* point on the line in a `Tooltip` or coordinates of the original interpolation points? Also note that the interpolation method which `ListPlot` uses [differs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3864709/590388) from the default interpolation method in `Interpolation`.

Comment: I would like any point on the curve.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, each one is interesting, the one of Fred Simons is closest to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return coordinates on the interpolated line

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}} // Transpose;

f = Interpolation[data,
   InterpolationOrder -> 2];

Tooltip[Plot[f[x],
  {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}],
 Dynamic[{#, f[#]} &@
   MousePosition["Graphics"][[1]]]]
```

For multiple data sets

```
data = {
   {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}},
   {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 4}},
   {{1, 4}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}}};

{min, max} =
  #[Flatten[data, 1][[All, 1]]] & /@
   {Min, Max};

funcs[x_] = #[x] & /@
   (Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 2] & /@
     data);

Tooltip[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[funcs[x]],
  {x, min, max}],
 Dynamic[
  {mpx, mpy} = MousePosition["Graphics"];
  fy = Nearest[funcs[mpx], mpy][[1]];
  Style[{mpx, fy}, 14]]]
```

Comment: Note that [`ListPlot` interpolates each coordinate as a function of the *list index*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3864709/590388).

Comment: @Bob would you know how to display a different tooltip for different curves ?

Comment: See addition above

Comment: That's perfect thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

The following command produces a graph, of which the coordinates of the points are shown in a tooltip when the mouse is over it.

```
 Tooltip[ListLinePlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}} // Transpose, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 2], Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ListLinePlot[Tooltip @ Cases[
   ListLinePlot[Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}],
     Mesh -> All,
     InterpolationOrder -> 2][[1, 2]],
   {a_Real, b_Real}, -1],
 Filling -> Bottom,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

Similarly for `InterpolationOrder -> 0`

```
ListLinePlot[Tooltip @ Sort @ Cases[
    ListLinePlot[Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}],
      Mesh -> All,
      InterpolationOrder -> 0][[1, 2]],
    {a_Real, b_Real}, -1],
 Filling -> Bottom,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 Mesh -> All,
 MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red]]
```

[image]

**Update**

If you want to specify the number of mesh points a more complicated approach is required

```
With[{points = 10},
 Show[
    #,
    ListPlot[
     Tooltip @ Take[Cases[#[[1, 2]], {a_Real, b_Real}, -1], -points],
     PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red]]
    ] &
  [
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}],
   Frame -> True,
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   Mesh -> points - 1,
   InterpolationOrder -> 2
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've generalised the answer of Bob Hanlon as I used it in many parts of my code.
The function takes as argument: a list of functions, a range for the x axis, an optional callback function, optional options of Plot, optional options of Tooltip.

**Example**

```
MouseOverPlot[
    {#^2&,#^3&},{0,5},
    "Callback"->
        Function[{xValue,functionValues,functionIndex},
            Column[
                {
                    "x: "~~ToString@xValue,
                    {"x^2","x^3"}[[functionIndex]]~~": "~~ToString@functionValues[[functionIndex]]
                }
            ]
        ]
]
```

**Code**

```
(*callback[xValue,functionValues,functionIndex]*)
Options[MouseOverPlot] = Join[{"Callback"->({#1,#2[[#3]]}&)},Options@Plot,Options@Tooltip];
MouseOverPlot[functions_,plotRange_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
    DynamicModule[{mousePosition,xValue,yValue,functionValues,funcs,functionIndex,callback,newPlotRange,xPlot},

        funcs[x_] = #[x]& /@ functions // Quiet;
        callback = OptionValue@"Callback";
        newPlotRange = Prepend[plotRange,xPlot];


        With[{newPlotRange=newPlotRange,options=FilterRules[{opts},Options@Plot]},
            Tooltip[
                Plot[
                    Evaluate[funcs[xPlot]]
                    ,
                    newPlotRange
                    ,
                    options
                ]
                ,
                Dynamic[
                    mousePosition = MousePosition["Graphics"];

                    If[mousePosition =!= None,

                        {xValue,yValue}=mousePosition;
                        functionValues = funcs[xValue];
                        functionIndex=Nearest[functionValues->Automatic,yValue][[1]];

                        callback[xValue,functionValues,functionIndex]
                        ,
                        ""
                    ]
                ]
                ,
                FilterRules[{opts},Options@Tooltip]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```